# upload frames from ARSession to firebase storage in real time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, arkit, swift-concurrency

I'm trying to stream frames from `ARSession` to Firebase Storage in real-time. There is some preprocessing that is done on frames before they are sent to firebase. The flow of app is as follows.

The `frameCount` variable is used used to name the image files in database. I want the images to be named in sequence as they were captured. The files are being uploaded successfully, the problems are:

1. It is not real-time because `upload()` runs asynchronously and takes some time.
2. The images are not uploaded in a sequence. I want them to be uploaded in same sequence as they are captured. The async part is doing something that is not intended with the `count` variable. From several hours of debugging I found that the same value of `count` is used multiple times for different frames. Uploading is all over the place. The `frameCount` reaches to 100 but uploading lags at 5-10. Then, when I stop the session, the uploading part continues but in random order. For example, it would upload the file `98.jpg` and the next one would be `5.jpg`.

```swift
var frameCount = 0

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    frameCount += 1
    queue.async {
        process(frame: frame, count: frameCount)
    }
}

func process(frame: ARFrame, count: Int) {
    // all the processing happens here to get jpg data of the image
    var imgData = ...
    var fileURL = writeToFile(imageData: imgData, count: count)
    upload(fileURL: fileURL, count: count)
}

func writeToFile(imageData: Data, count: Int) -> URL {
    jpgFileURL = try getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(count).jpg")
    try jpgData.write(to: jpgFileURL!)
    return jpgFileURL
}

func upload(fileURL: URL, count: Int) {
    let imageFileRef = storageRef.child("\(count).jpg")
    imageFileRef.putFile(from: fileURL) // this part runs asynchronously
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of `DispatchQueue`, `async`-`await` keywords, `TaskGroup`, etc. but nothing seems to work. At the core, I just want to increment the `frameCount`, write data to file, and upload in sequential manner. This pipeline for next frame should stack over execution of previous frame and should wait for it to upload successfully.

Comment: @Rob yes you are correct. It was a typo. It is queue.async{...}

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you want to make sure to not reference a mutating property in your closure. So, for example, you want to reference a copy of `frameCount`. To make a copy of this, use a “capture list”. So rather than …

```swift
dispatchQueue.async {
    process(frame: frame, count: frameCount)
}
```

Instead use …

```swift
dispatchQueue.async { [frameCount] in
    process(frame: frame, count: frameCount)
}
```

That will still not upload them in order, but it will ensure that they at least have the the current, unique, value of `frameCount` and are therefore properly named.

---

Now, I don’t know how many frames you are dealing with, but this can easily suffer from “thread explosion”, and it might behave strangely once you have more than 64 frames backlogged. You might want to constrain that to some reasonable number. You can do that with an `OperationQueue`:

```swift
var frameCount = 0
let operationQueue: OperationQueue = {
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "frame.queue"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 6
    return queue
}()
    
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    frameCount += 1
    operationQueue.addOperation { [frameCount] in
        process(frame: frame, count: frameCount)
    }
}
```

Or Swift concurrency:

```swift
var frameCount = 0
    
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    frameCount += 1
    Task.detached { [frameCount] in
        process(frame: frame, count: frameCount)
    }
}
```

---

There are ways to make this run sequentially (in order, one at a time), too, but that will make it run even slower. I bet you already aren’t keeping up with your “real-time” goal, and making this asynchronous task run serially will likely only make that worse.

Comment: Please note that the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool is artificially constrained on the simulator. Make sure to test on physical device if testing parallelism in Swift concurrency.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I'm testing it on a real device. Regarding the real-time solution, I can settle for a lesser frame rate, and it doesn't have to be sequential. Is there a way to prioritize tasks and run asynchronously?

Comment: The order is actually really important for the application. Making the frame rate slower and size of files smaller might work better. Can you give me a hint on how I can make it run sequentially?

Comment: The order of the final result is always important. But we often use an order-independent structure (e.g., a dictionary keyed by frame number rather than an array of frames) for gathering the results. But if you can live with making it 5-10 times slower (which is, admittedly, antithetical to real-time processing), then go ahead and use a serial GCD queue and a synchronous Firebase call.